# iconv() UTF8 to ISO-8859-1 with accents

Tags: php, string, utf-8

I have a string in PHP in UTF-8 so i try to convert it to ISO-8859-1. The string is in Spanish, so it contains special accents and characters like áéíóúñ...

If i try with

```
$actual = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $actual);
```

It says that there are some incorrect characters, and if i try with

```
$actual = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $actual);
```

It makes the file, but the special characters are now replaced with "·"

How can i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are all "special characters" replaced with "·"? Do you get one "·" per "special character"

Comment: Stupid question but are you sure `$actual` contains UTF-8?

Comment: Yep, mb_check_encoding($actual ,"UTF-8") returns true

Comment: The string given (`áéíóúñ`) seems to work fine. Can you share the problematic string?